# Domain name prefix

Tags: web-services, url, dns, subdomain

How to create domain names like

```
maps.google.com

mail.google.com

docs.google.com
```

and etc...

My company having departments ike trade, health etc,.

So I would like to manage my domain names as follows

```
Trade.mycompanyname.com

Health.mycompanyname.com
```

So how to register such kind of names...

I registered `mycompanyname.com` already

And

1. How to host a single web application with two different domain names?
2. What is Host Domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add subdomains, just create new subdirectories in the `/htdocs` directory.

For instance, if you had the domain name `abc.com` and wanted a subdomain for `123`, then you would just create the directory `/htdocs/123` and upload the files in there that you wanted to see at `http://123.abc.com`